# How to log an unauthorized user (401) when they try to access a webapp in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-restcontroller

I feel like this should be a pretty easy fix with a logger or something, but I don't have much experience with using one. I'm simply trying to log the unauthorized user when I get a 401 error from my webapp's rest api. Here's the current rest controller:

```
@RestController
public class bagelController {

@Autowired
private bagelService bagelService;

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@GetMapping("/rest/bagel/search")
public ResponseEntity<Bagel> searchBagel (@RequestParam(value = "bagel", required = false) String bagel, 
        @RequestParam(value = "bagelInd", required = false, defaultValue = "1") int bagelInd) {

    ResponseEntity<Bagel> response;
    Bagel bagel = null;
    if(!userService.getCurrentUser().isBagelEditAccess()) {
        response = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        //I'd want to log the unauthorized user right here I believe
    }
    else {
        bagel = bagelService.getbagel(bagel, bagelInd);
        if (bagel == null) {
            response = ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        else {
            response = ResponseEntity.ok(cnl);
        }
    } 
    return response; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare logger and print using log.info()......

import this:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
```

code:

```
@RestController
public class bagelController {

    private final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Autowired
    private bagelService bagelService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/rest/bagel/search")
    public Bagel searchBagel (@RequestParam(value = "bagel", required = false) String bagel,
                              @RequestParam(value = "bagelInd", required = false, defaultValue = "1") int bagelInd) {

        Bagel bagel = null;
        if(!userService.getCurrentUser().isBagelEditAccess()) {
            response = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
            //I'd want to log the unauthorized user right here I believe
            log.info("Unauthorized User: "+userService.getCurrentUser());
        }
        else {
            bagel = bagelService.getbagel(bagel, bagelInd);
            if (bagel == null) {
                response = ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
            }
            else {
                response = ResponseEntity.ok(cnl);
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Aha, okay. Thanks for that! I'm new to quite a bit of this stuff.

Comment: Actually it looks like I'm having an issue. This may be my fault for not initially showing that I had the ResponseEntity<Bagel> in there. I'm getting the error 

    "The method getLogger(String) in the type LogManager is not applicable for the arguments (Class<CnlLetterController>)"

Comment: just call getLogger without params

Comment: I don't believe that I can. It requires a string

Comment: Fantastic. I was importing java.util logger instead of the apache logger. That cleared it all up.